# FlatList search bar does not persist keyboard React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm fetching data from an API and implementing search in a FlatList but the keyboard dismisses automatically after every key-press.
I'm refering [this article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-a-react-native-flatlist-with-realtime-searching-ability-81ad100f6699/) but implementing it in a Functional Component.

```
 const renderHeader = () => {
        return <SearchBar 
        placeholder="Type Here..." 
        lightTheme 
        round
        onChangeText={text => searchFilterFunction(text)}
        value={value}
        autoCorrect={false} />;
    }

 const searchFilterFunction = (text) => {
        setValue(text);
        const newData = APIData.filter(item => {
            const itemData = `${item.name.toUpperCase()}`;
            const textData = text.toUpperCase();
            return itemData.includes(textData);
        });
        setData(newData);
    }

 return (
    <FlatList
    keyExtractor={(item) => item._id}
    data={data}
    ItemSeparatorComponent={renderSeparator}
    ListHeaderComponent={renderHeader}
    ListFooterComponent={renderFooter}
    onRefresh={handleRefresh}
    refreshing={refreshing}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <Card>
            <Card.Content style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                <Text>{"Name: " + item.name}</Text>
                <Text>{"Status: " + (item.isaccepted ? "Accepted" : "Pending")}</Text>
                <Text>{"ID: " + item.id}</Text>
            </Card.Content>
        </Card>
    )} />
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing same thing, adding search bar as a header to FlatList. Unfortunately, this also updates the header when you update the flatlist data when search filtering is complete and hence focusing out of SearchBar. At the end, due to time constraints, I ended up putting SearchBar at the top of FlatList.

Answer (score 1):

Try rendering your ListHeaderComponent as JSX element directly, instead of using callback

```
<FlatList
    ListHeaderComponent={
      <View>
       <Text>I am the header</Text>
      </View>
    }
    ...props
/>
```