# Issue with Unexpected Keyboard Closing in React Native When Using a SectionList with an Input in the Header

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm facing a problem in React Native involving a SectionList with a ListHeaderComponent. In the list's header, I have an input field that should make an API request when changed (onChangeText). The API response should then be used to update the component's state, specifically a data array used by the SectionList.

My main issue is that when I click on the input field and start typing, the keyboard unexpectedly closes after entering the first character. I've looked into various solutions found online, but it appears that the issue is caused by a re-render of the header component when the data array of the SectionList is updated. I would like to avoid this re-render of the header, but at the same time, I need to update the data array for the SectionList.

I've considered the option of moving the input outside of the header, but due to the use of the SectionList, I can't simply insert a ScrollView at a higher level.

What are the possible solutions or suggestions for addressing this issue without causing the header to re-render when I update the data array of the SectionList?

I have tried searching for solutions online and considered some possible alternatives, but so far, I haven't been able to resolve the issue. I expected to be able to type into the keyboard input without any issues and have the SectionList updated with data obtained from the API call without the keyboard automatically closing.

For the code is similar to: [FlatList search bar does not persist keyboard React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62148855/flatlist-search-bar-does-not-persist-keyboard-react-native)